# get_the_term_list by hierarchy order

Tags: posts, categories

```
    function btp_entry_capture_categories() {
        $out = '';

        global $post;

        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post );

        foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {  
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );  
            if ( $taxonomy->query_var && $taxonomy->hierarchical ) {

                $out .= '<div class="entry-categories">';
                    $out .= '<h6>' . $taxonomy->labels->name . '</h6>';
                    $out .= get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $taxonomy->name, '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', ' › </li></ul>' );
                $out .= '</div>';
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }
```

I'm trying to output the category list ordering by hierarchy, is it possible to do with my code? what would be the best approach to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "output the category list ordering by hierarchy"

Comment: Now it outputs like this: Artist, Books, etc (in ASC). But now I want it to get the hierarchy which in this case it would be Books > Artist

Comment: So you need `parent >> child >> grandchild; parent >> child >> grandchild;`

Comment: @PieterGoosen yeah, that's exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_the_term_list()` will not work here. The best function to use would be [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

With the following assumption, this can work

- If a post only belongs to one parent, one child and/or one grandchild, you can order the terms by `term_id`.
- It is widely accepted that the parent will have a lower numbered ID than the child and the child will have a lower numbered ID than the grandchild

With this info, you can get the post terms as follow then inside your code

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy->name, array( 'orderby' => 'term_id' ) );
```

But as I said, you will need to have your post have only one parent, one child and one grandchild in the same tree

**EDIT**

You can try something like this. You will just need to add the HTML mark-up yourself

```
function btp_entry_capture_categories() {
    $out = '';

    global $post;

    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post );

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {  
        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );  
        if ( $taxonomy->query_var && $taxonomy->hierarchical ) {

            $out .= '<div class="entry-categories">';
                $out .= '<h6>' . $taxonomy->labels->name . '</h6>';

                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy->name, array( 'orderby' => 'term_id' ) );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                    $out .= $term->name;

                }
            $out .= '</div>';
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: thanks Pieter, I'm trying with your code but I get the following error: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string`

Comment: Yes, you need to use a `foreach` loop, `wp_get_post_terms` returns an object, not a string like `get_the_term_list`

Comment: mmm I'm using it, see it in the question? :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me there, :-). Check my update

Comment: 'It is widely accepted that the parent will have a lower numbered ID than the child and the child will have a lower numbered ID than the grandchild'

This statement is utterly false, it's completely possible to have parents with lower ids than their children, since they can be assigned after creation, making this answer very inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that sorts the terms in a hierarchical order:

```
function sort_terms_by_hierarchy($terms, &$sorted_terms = array(), $parent_id = 0) {
    if (empty($terms)) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
        if ($term->parent == $parent_id) {
            $sorted_terms[] = $term;
            unset($terms[$key]);
            sort_terms_by_hierarchy($terms, $sorted_terms, $term->term_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use this function to sort the categories returned by the wp_get_post_terms() function:

```
// Get the product categories
$product_categories = wp_get_post_terms($current_product_id, 'product_cat');

// Sort the categories by hierarchy
$sorted_categories = array();
sort_terms_by_hierarchy($product_categories, $sorted_categories);

// Loop through the categories and get the nested categories order for each category
foreach ($sorted_categories as $category) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty fix you can use the "term_links-{$taxonomy}" hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_links-taxonomy/

You can add this f.i. to your functions.php file in your theme.

```
// Sorting of taxonomies
function xcustom_sort_taxonomies($taxonomies)
{
    $categories = get_categories();
    usort($taxonomies, function ($a, $b) use ($categories) {
        $aCat = 0;
        $bCat = 0;
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if (str_contains($a, $category->name)) {
                $aCat = $category;
            }
            if (str_contains($b, $category->name)) {
                $bCat = $category;
            }
        }
        return $aCat->parent - $bCat->parent;
    });

    return $taxonomies;
}
add_action('term_links-category', 'xcustom_sort_taxonomies', 10, 3);
```